# how to cross the SOSl query Limit

Tags: apex

I have a class with SOQL and SOSL query. the SOQL query fetches List of unique emails from an object.The emails in the List are then passed to the SOSl query. the Problem is the List has more than 20 emails and the Limit for SOSL query is 20 per transaction. so the remaining emails in the List are not getting processed.

How to process all the emails..

Pls Help..

```
public void getAllAccount(Map<String , List<Subscription__c>> sub_Map){
uniqueEmail = sub_Map.keySet(); 
for(String email : uniqueEmail ) { 
    acc_List = [find :email IN Email FIELDS RETURNING Account (Store_number__c) ]; 
    if(acc_List != null || acc_List.size()>0) { 
        if(sub_Map.get(email).size()!= acc_List.size()) { 
            for(subscription__c trueupMails : sub_Map.get(email)) { 
                trueUp_List.add(trueupMails);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste you code here? looks like you're using the SOSL in for loop, which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: hi sameer, thanks for quick response. you are correct. I am iterating the list and running the SOSL query for each value.So..if that's an imperfect way.. how should I make that happen...?

Comment: here is my code..public void getAllAccount(Map<String , List<Subscription__c>> sub_Map){uniqueEmail  = sub_Map.keySet();   
for(String email : uniqueEmail )
   {
   
acc_List = [find :email IN Email FIELDS RETURNING Account (Store_number__c) ];
     
        if(acc_List != null || acc_List.size()>0)
         {
            if(sub_Map.get(email).size()!= acc_List.size())
            {
                for(subscription__c trueupMails : sub_Map.get(email))
                {
                trueUp_List.add(trueupMails);
                }}}    
        
    
       
     
             }
}

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code helps!

```
public void getAllAccount(Map<String , List<Subscription__c>> sub_Map){
//creating a map of email and the associated Accounts
map<string, list<account>> accEmailMap = new map<string, list<account>>();
Query all the accounts in the a single qurewy and loop thru it.
for(account a : [select email, id from account where email IN : sub_Map.keySet()]){

    //Check if the the emai lis already present in the map. if yes then get the list and add a new records to the list and then push the account details to the map. If the map doesn't have the mail then add the account record in the map as done in the else block.

    if(accEmailMap.containsKey(a.email)){
        list<account> tempAcc = accEmailMap.get(a.email);
        tempAcc.add(a);
        accEmailMap.put(a.email, tempAcc);
    }else{
        list<account> tempAc = new list<account>();
        tempAc.add(a);
        accEmailMap.put(a.email,tempAc);
    }
}

//Original for loop
for(string email: sub_Map.keySet()){
    //check if the email is presen tin the map.
    if(accEmailMap.containsKey(email)){
        // the original condition which you were checking.
        if(sub_Map.get(email).size()!= accEmailMap.get(email).size()){
            for(subscription__c trueupMails : sub_Map.get(email)) { 
                trueUp_List.add(trueupMails);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: hi sameer,  i need to add these details. My account is of type store with 15 email fields. any of these fields may contain the value being searched. so i cannot apply "where" condition on any specific email fields....